# Get unique column values from an array of objects

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, unique, array-column

I have an array of objects.

What I need is to take each `[name]` of each object in put into another array, but I don't want duplicates.

How can I do it?

```
Array (
    [0] => ADOFetchObj Object
        (
            [name] => Team 1
            [att] => None
            [idGrupo] => 1
            [idModulo] => 4
            [ler] => 1
            [escrever] => 1
            [excluir] => 1
        )

    [1] => ADOFetchObj Object
        (
            [name] => Team 1
            [nomeModulo] => Aplicar Juros
            [idGrupo] => 1
            [idModulo] => 1006
            [ler] => 1
            [escrever] => 1
            [excluir] => 1
        )

    [2] => ADOFetchObj Object
        (
            [name] => Team 2
            [att] => None
            [idGrupo] => 1
            [idModulo] => 10
            [ler] => 1
            [escrever] => 1
            [excluir] => 1
        )

    [3] => ADOFetchObj Object
        (
            [name] => Team 2
            [att] => None
            [idGrupo] => 1
            [idModulo] => 1012
            [ler] => 1
            [escrever] => 1
            [excluir] => 1
        )
)
```

Comment: I don't understand. What happens when you have two identical names? How do you know which to choose?

Comment: I want to take every `[name]`of this array above and put into another array, but wihtout duplicates. Got it?

Comment: @PédeLeão Well... they're the same, so what does it matter?

Comment: @RocketHazmat Internal placeholder for record objects. Used by ADORecordSet->FetchObj().

Comment: @LucasVeiga: This is an array of objects, not an array of arrays.

Comment: @WaleedKhan ... I get it now. I didn't understand what he was asking at first.

Comment: on what criteria do you merge objects? last? newest (though no time field)? ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$names = array();
foreach($arr as $list) {
    $names[$list->name] = true; // can be *any* arbitrary value
}
$names = array_keys($names);
```

This will work because by definition array keys have to be unique.

Comment: No problem @LucasVeiga happy to help ^_^

Comment: This is probably the most efficient way.

Comment: @netcoder yea... I do not understand all the `if` statements and `array_unique`'s in the other answers... they add too much overhead :-P

Comment: Well this one is definitely the most elegant but not really the easiest to understand for a beginner imho ;)

Comment: @Intrepidd what is _hard_ to understand? I will try to explain it better.

Comment: I did not say it was hard ;)

Comment: Ok then... that is _not easy_ to understand? @Intrepidd

Comment: I just think beginners could have trouble understanding why you are setting the value to true just in order to get an array of unique keys, but since @LucasVeiga understood it, i guess other people will, so no problem, kudos for the great answer ;)

Comment: @Intrepidd oh you can set the value to anything. I just used true as an example.

Answer (score 3):

```
array_unique(array_map(function($element) {
    return $element->name;
}, $my_array));
```

Comment: +1 As far as I'm concerned, this is the only answer worth looking at. The standard library solves this problem without the need for a loop.

Answer (score 3):

There you go

```
$res = array();

foreach($arr as $var)
{
    if(!in_array($var->name, $res))
    {
      $res[] = $var->name;
    }
}
```

Comment: `$var` is an object, not an array. Did anybody read this question properly before answering it?

Comment: Corrected, description was misleading : "I have an array inside of another array."

Answer (score 2):

First, copy the names to a new array:

```
$arrNames = array();

foreach($arrOriginal as $objObject) {
    array_push(
        $arrNames,
        $objObject->name
    );
}
```

Then remove the duplicate names:

```
$arrNames = array_unique($arrNames);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$n = array();

foreach($array as $d) $n[] = $d->name;

$n = array_unique($n);
```